# flask-wtf HiddenField doesn't resturn any data

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I got an issue when using **HiddenField**, i cant'get the data from it
the form is rendred properly

```html
 {{form.user_id(value=user.id)}}
```

```py
class EditUserForm(FlaskForm):

   username = StringField("Username", validators=[
                    DataRequired(), Length(min=5, max=20)])
   email = StringField("Email", validators=[Email()])
   password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
   password_confirmation = PasswordField("Confirm Password", validators= 
                                           [EqualTo('password')])
   role = SelectField('Role',
                            choices=[(Role.name, Role.value)
                                    for Role in Roles],
                            default=Roles.admin.value)

   user_id = HiddenField("user.id")

   submit = SubmitField("Save")

   def validate_username(self, username):

        #run validation only if the username has changed

        user = User.query.get(self.user_id.data)
        if username.data != user.username:
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
            if user:
                raise ValidationError(f"{self.username.data} is already taken")

   def validate_email(self, email):

        #run validation only if the email has changed

        user = User.query.get(self.user_id.data)
        if email.data != user.email:
            email = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
            if email:
                raise ValidationError(f"{self.email.data} is already taken")
```

---

when i tried to use **StringField** and set type="hidden"

```
{{form.user_id(type="hidden, value=user.id)}}
```

it does work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in html-template:

```
{{ form.user_id() }}
```

Create hidden form field:

```
   user_id = HiddenField('user_id', default=user.id)
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Comment: @JeremyCaney adjusted

Comment: i cant use this the user.id is sent from template, i used StringField like i said and set the type to hidden im just wondering why the HiddenField always returns empty string